# Change power key behaviour

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

I've paired a Bluetooth remote to a Raspberry Pi ZW with Raspbian Buster Lite. One of the buttons sends the power key on a long press. This causes the RPi to shutdown immediately. This is a bit brutal and I would like to this prevent this and to handle this key in my application. While looking on forums about changing the behaviour of the power key I've seen answers talking about configuration under /etc/acpi but it doesn't seem to exist under Raspbian Buster Lite.

Does anyone know what configuration needs to be done to prevent immediate shutdown on reception of the power key?

Thanks